# Community Wiki answer in bounty question

Tags: support, answers, bounty, community-wiki

If I use Community Wiki while answering a bounty question, is it possible to earn the bounty?

I know I will not earn the upvotes on Community Wiki answer.

Comment: Yes, you will. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20931/can-a-community-wiki-answer-win-the-bounty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will earn the bounty even if the answer is a Community Wiki.

From the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065)

> #### How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?
>
> Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.